# Windows 10 version next update apeared on a windows 11 preview build

Tags: windows, updates, windows-11, windows-11-preview

I have seen that I have an update on my secondary machine with windows 11, now problem is, the update says it's for Windows 10 Version Next and it's some cumulative update for the .NET framework 3.5 and 4.8 for devices based on x64 processors (KB5004034).

Is this normal and should I install it or will it break the windows 11 installation?
Is it tied to windows 10 machines or something?

This may sound dumb but knowing Microsoft and windows updates anything can happen. :/

Please provide an answer because I'm unsure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updates for the .NET framework can be installed safely.

The "Windows 10" label is probably an oversight and not a problem.

In any case, I suggest to verify that System Restore is enabled on your
computer, and to create a restore point before launching the update.
This is also the minimum that I advise to do before any Windows update.

Comment: Windows 11 at this point is Windows 10 (granted a higher build), this is evident by the fact an Insider Preview build of Windows 10 can be upgraded to an Insider Preview build of Windows 11.  Microsoft has been releasing updates for multiple versions of Windows 10 for more than a year.  While I agree the label might be an oversight the patch compatibility with Windows 11 isn’t.